# Matlab measure pulse width and plot over time for jitter evaluation

Tags: matlab, plot, pwm, jitter

I want to measure the low pulse length of a signal and then plot it to see if the pwm ratio changes during run time of that signal.

The signal it self was acquired using an oscilloscope and stored as a *cvs* file, channel 2 is a pulse signal where i want to evaluate in which boundaries the pulses are steady or not.

`with d = dutycycle(CH2)`

i could get the duty cycle from my signal

How can i plot the dutycycle or low pulse time as a graphical line or field to see its changes over time?

Both Files for Testing are here:

- [First](http://hopiberg.bplaced.net/upload/csvread.V1.m)
- [Second](http://hopiberg.bplaced.net/upload/SIGNAL.CSV)

Comment: Well i found that with 'code' p      =   pulsewidth(CH2, TIME, 'Polarity', 'Negative');'code' i could measure the low puls length something i absolutely wanted... My next issues would be how to evenly space the low time over the pulse signal to get a feeling for pulse length changes

Answer (score 0):

Your signal is quite clean, so you could just use simple thresholding.  If you needed to handle a little more noise, here's one way.

The basic approach is to decompose the signal piecewise (into a sequence of constant segments).  Changepoint identification gives you the start and end time as well as magnitude of each segment.

[image]

Then, all the even times are rising edges and odd times are falling edges (or vice versa).  The differences between these two vectors give high and low duration of each pulse, and differences between rising edges gives per-pulse duration.

```
rising = TIME(1+est.time(2:2:end));
falling = TIME(1+est.time(1:2:end));
hightime = falling(2:end) - rising(1:end-1); 
lowtime = rising(2:end) - falling(2:end);
plot([lowtime hightime diff(rising)])
legend('Low Time', 'High Time', 'Pulse Duration')
```

[image: Analysis Results: Low, High, and Cycle durations]

Duty cycle is then `hightime ./ diff(rising)`, and you can proceed with your jitter calculations.

For performing the segmentation, I used code from my thesis, but this simple case (piecewise constant) was already solved by Killick et. al (2012)

> [R. Killick, P. Fearnhead, and I. A. Eckley. Optimal detection of changepoints with a linear computational cost. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 107(500):1590–1598, Dec 2012. doi: 10.1080/01621459.2012.737745.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2012.737745)

Comment: How do you plot with alternating colours? That looks cool!..Thank you for your input... i tried peakfinder function from Matlabs Fileexchange as i couldn't find changepoint identification inside my labview installation ^^  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder-x0--sel--thresh--extrema--includeendpoints--interpolate-